# Tree view with floating window

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

When I move my mouse to a row in tree view and stay here for a second, I want to see a floating window. (Like in developer mode.)

How Can I solve it? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your field or fields that get rendered on a listview make sure you give to the `__init__` method the `help='My Floating Test'` argument. That will cause a floating window to be shown when you hover on that field.

For example check:

`addons/account/models/account.py`

```
tag_ids = fields.Many2many('account.account.tag', 'account_account_account_tag', string='Tags', help="Optional tags you may want to assign for custom reporting")
```

The string on the help attribu will be shown on all the views that render this field upon hovering on it and pausing for 1 second.

If you want to modify the window that is shown, you can extend the 
`t-name="WidgetLabel.tooltip"` template that is located in `addons/web/static/src/xml/base_common.xml`

Comment: I know it, but this is only a static string. What I want is a dynamic content, for example: image or some of filed value etc.

Comment: Can you give me more information about it? Possibly an example. Honesty, I never do same, this widgetlabel thing is new for me. Can you give me some of description? Where did you learn it?